# UITableView selection disappears when swiping left/right

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview and selected a random row. When I right/left swipe any cell in the table view to perform implemented action, immediately tableview selection disappears. After I complete/cancel the right/left swipe action tableview has no selected items.

I have stored the selected item details and I can reselect the cell. But in which method I should reselect the item? If the custom action is completed then I can reselect the cell. If the custom action is cancelled(swiped in opposite direction to close the custom action buttons) then how can I reselect the cell?

Comment: Take a look at [didEndEditingRowAt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614963-tableview)

Comment: @DonMag It works. Thanks